# Подскажите как сократить код на jQuery (событие при hover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста как сократить код?

```
  $('.section-first').hover(function() {
    $('#primary a:not(.section-first)').addClass('swing')
  }, function() {
    $('#primary a:not(.section-first)').removeClass('swing')
  });

  $('.section-second').hover(function() {
   $('#primary a:not(.section-second)').addClass('swing')
  }, function() {
    $('#primary a:not(.section-second)').removeClass('swing')
  });

  $('.section-third').hover(function() {
    $('#primary a:not(.section-third)').addClass('swing')
  }, function() {
    $('#primary a:not(.section-third)').removeClass('swing')
  });

  $('.section-fourth').hover(function() {
     $('#primary a:not(.section-fourth)').addClass('swing')
  }, function() {
    $('#primary a:not(.section-fourth)').removeClass('swing')
  });

  $('.section-fifth').hover(function() {
     $('#primary a:not(.section-fifth)').addClass('swing')
  }, function() {
    $('#primary a:not(.section-fifth)').removeClass('swing')
  });

  $('.section-sixth').hover(function() {
     $('#primary a:not(.section-sixth)').addClass('swing')
  }, function() {
    $('#primary a:not(.section-sixth)').removeClass('swing')
  });
```

Comment: Элементов с каждым классом `section-X` сколько штук? По одному на класс или может быть несколько? И есть ли ещё `<a>` кроме представленных?

Comment: Всего 6. По одному на класс. а тоже 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно добавлять/удалять класс "всем `<a>` в контейнере кроме данного", то можно сделать так:

```js
var $links = $("#primary a");
$links.hover(function() {
  $links.not(this).addClass("swing");
}, function() {
  $links.not(this).removeClass("swing");
});
```

```css
.swing {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary">
  <a href="">First</a>
  <a href="">Second</a>
  <a href="">Third</a>
  <a href="">Forth</a>
  <a href="">Fifth</a>
  <a href="">Sixth</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваше решение сработало.

Answer (score 2):

Может глупость напишу, но думаю так:

```
$('#primary a').hover(function() {
  $('#primary a').not(this).toggleClass('swing');
});
```

Этот код проверил. Работает. ))

Comment: Увы, не проверял. Вы правы, следовало бы наверное писать .not( $(this) ).

Comment: Вы снова правы, сейчас исправлю код.

Answer (score 1):

```
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth'].forEach(counter => {
  $(`.section-${counter}`).hover(function() {
     $(`#primary a:not(.section-${counter})`).addClass('swing')
  }, function() {
    $(`#primary a:not(.section-${counter})`).removeClass('swing')
  });
});
```